# Output cross referential Matrix results in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have a primary table with 4 records with Id 1 through 4

I then have a transactional table that maintains the compatibility of one record to another

```
Record1    Record2    IsCompatible
1          2          True
1          3          True
4          1          False
2          3          False
4          2          True
3          4          True
```

There will only ever be one record with the same Record1 / Record2 combination, but of those records the logic determining if a given record is held as Record1 or Record2 is dependant on what the source record was when the compatibility was set. As such any record could be either way round at any time.

From this I want to output a recordset that looks something like this:

```
RecordID    CompatabilityString
1           Null, True, True, False
2           True, Null, False, True
3           True, False, Null, True
4           False, True, True, Null
```

The CompatabilityString returns the compatibility of each item to all other items in numerical order, with null representing the relationship with itself.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should UNION this table with it self to get a full matrix and then PIVOT this table using `MAX(CASE...)`:

```
SELECT X,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Y=1 THEN IsCompatible END) as Y1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Y=2 THEN IsCompatible END) as Y2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Y=3 THEN IsCompatible END) as Y3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Y=4 THEN IsCompatible END) as Y4

FROM
(
    SELECT Record1 as X,Record2 as Y,IsCompatible FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Record2 as X,Record1 as Y,IsCompatible FROM T
) as T1
GROUP BY X
ORDER BY X
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aeee/2)</kbd>

If you need only one column for `CompatabilityString`:

```
SELECT X as RecordID,
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Y=1 THEN IsCompatible END),'NULL')+
       ','+       
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Y=2 THEN IsCompatible END),'NULL')+
       ','+       
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Y=3 THEN IsCompatible END),'NULL')+
       ','+       
       ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Y=4 THEN IsCompatible END),'NULL')
       as CompatabilityString 


FROM
(
    SELECT Record1 as X,Record2 as Y,IsCompatible FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Record2 as X,Record1 as Y,IsCompatible FROM T
) as T1
GROUP BY X
ORDER BY X
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aeee/4)</kbd>

**UPD:** Here is the second query for the case of variable dimensions. In this case `FOR XML PATH` is used to make a comma delimited list:

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT Record1 as X,Record2 as Y,IsCompatible FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Record2 as X,Record1 as Y,IsCompatible FROM T
) 

SELECT DISTINCT X,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + ISNULL(IsCompatible,'NULL')
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT X as Y FROM T1) as Tbase
          LEFT JOIN T1 AS T2
               ON TBase.Y=T2.Y AND T1.X = T2.X
          ORDER BY TBase.Y
          FOR XML PATH ('')
          )
          , 1, 1, '')  AS COMPATABILITYSTRING
FROM T1
ORDER BY X
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aeee/9)</kbd>

Comment: I like the option of actually outputting the values as columns rather than a comma delimited string, however the example was just that. In reality there could be 100+ records that need to be cross referenced so the columns would need to be built dynamically. Is this possible?

Comment: Also the same applies to the second example. How can this be done dynamically

Comment: @StewartAlan: I've added the query to make a comma delimited list for the variable dimension to my answer. If you need the separated columns instead then this can be done only with dynamic SQL.